# 404 not found error using ServiceStack ServerEventsClient with Pipedream SSE API

Tags: c#, servicestack, dotnet-httpclient, server-sent-events, pipedream

I'm using [Pipedream](https://pipedream.com/) as a data source which provides event data via an SSE API.

As per the instructions [here](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client), I'm using the following code to subscribe to the SSE:

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient("https://api.pipedream.com/sources/dc_mXugEA/sse")
{
    EventStreamRequestFilter = req => req.AddBearerToken("[MYTOKEN]"),
    OnMessage = message => Console.WriteLine(message.Json)
}.Start();
```

However, I get a `System.Net.WebException` with the message 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

But if I use `HttpClient` directly, it succeeds:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "[MYTOKEN]");

using var reader = new StreamReader(await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.pipedream.com/sources/dc_mXugEA/sse"));
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {await reader.ReadLineAsync()}");
}
```

Of course, I want to use `ServerEventsClient` instead of `HttpClient` to avoid the boilerplate looping code. But why is `ServerEventsClient` not working in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack’s [Server Events clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client) only works with ServiceStack’s [Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) feature, I.e. it can’t be used to consume a 3rd Party SSE stream.

Comment: Guess that answers that then! Are there other options to subscribe to a third-party SSE stream beside the basic `HttpClient` one then?

Comment: @Neo I'm not familiar with any others, but I'd assume there would be.